# 12.10 doesn't recognize Integrated Graphics card of Intel g540

Tags: drivers, 12.10, intel-graphics

I couldn't find an answer to this question.

Does anyone know how to make Ubuntu recognize the Intel g540 Integrated Graphics card?

Answer (score 0):

Install mesa-utils by running these commands:

> sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install mesa-utils

Then it should work.